# What did I misunderstand about inner join meaning for wrds database?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, wrds

I learned join methods in sql, and I know that inner join means returning only the intersections of the two different tables that we want to set.

I thought for python the concept is same. But I have problem understanding the certain code.

`crsp1=pd.merge(crsp, crsp_maxme, how='inner', on=['jdate','permco','me'])`

`crsp1=crsp1.drop(['me'], axis=1)`

`crsp2=pd.merge(crsp1, crsp_summe, how='inner', on=['jdate','permco'])`

If I understood correctly, the first line merges table crsp and crsp_maxme with intersection on column 'jdate', 'permco', 'me'. So the table crsp1 would have 3 columns.
The second line drops the 'me' column of table crsp1.
The last lien would merge newly adjusted table crsp1 and crsp_summe with inner join, with intersection on 'jdate' and 'permco'. Which makes newly merged table crsp2 only having 2 columns.

However, the code explanation from line 2 says that the second and third lines drop 'me' column from crsp1 and then replace it with 'me' from crsp_summe table, which I had problem understanding.

Could anyone clarify these lines for me?

PS: I thought it isn't necessary to explain what the table crsp, crsp_summe, and crsp_maxme since they are all framed by inner join function.  So please excuse the lack of background info.

Comment: If you want to understand then study this using pure SQL. Any padding interferes with understanding.

Comment: "I know that inner join means returning only the intersections of the two different tables" -- not really. You can join using any predicate you want.

Comment: @TheImpaler Oh, I must have misunderstood the join concept about sql then:) So according to correct knowledge about the join methods, the explanation about replacing 'me' from 'crsp1' with 'me' from 'crsp_summe' is possible since inner join on 'jdate','permco' doesn't mean returning only 2 columns?

Comment: As @Akina says, if you want to understand SQL, use SQL. Pandas (for python) is not SQL

Comment: @cycla The confusion you have about joins is that you implicitly talk about "equi joins". The tool you are using in the example `on=['jdate','permco','me']` probably only implements this type of join, and that's OK; equi joins are the most common type of joins. Nevertheless, your tool is hiding a world of possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `merge()` functions `on` parameter specifies on what columns you want to make joins. `how` specifies what type of join you want to apply (similar to sql joins as outer, inner, left, right etc.).

Ex:
suppose there are two tables A and B containing columns as `A['x1','x2','x3']` and `B['x2','y1']` so joining them based on `'x1'` (as it is common column in both table) would produce `A_join_B_on_x1['A_B_x1','A_x2','A_x3','B_y1']` and the join will based on how you want to join.

in your current code consider,

```
A = crsp1
B = crsp_maxme
C = crsp_summe
```

Now in your program your
first line merges your `A,B` on `['jdate','permco','me']` columns and creates a new dataframe `A_B` containing `['jdate','permco','me',...'+columns_from_both_tables(A)(B)']` as inner join (i.e rows which are common in both A,B based on `['jdate','permco','me']` columns)

[image]

second line drops `'me'` column from `A_B` dataframe. so it will be something like
`['jdate','permco',...'+columns_from_both_tables(A)(B)']`

[image]

third line merges your `A_B,C` on `['jdate','permco']` and creates `['jdate','permco',...'+columns_from_both_tables(A_B)(C)']` as inner join (i.e rows which are common in both A_B,C based on `['jdate','permco','me']` columns)

[image]